# Google forms multiple choice grid: add "Other" option

Tags: google-forms, multiple-choice

I need to insert the option Other:____ in a multiple choice grid in google forms. In a multiple choice list there is the possibility, but I didn't find the same in a multiple choice grid. Anyone know if it is possible and how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such feature for grid question. It is not in alignment with the use of it.

Comment: It could be in alignment with the use of it. Like this: [multiple choice grid with other option](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o2pARbTXFoHJERlxz_vyImMR8sjO-GbD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what do you say with the screenshot. What you want is 'Other: (with input)'. It is not support by grid question.

Comment: Yes, I mean other: with input. Realised that it isn't supported. What a pity